# Changing xml or layout during runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, runtime

on my Android project I need to change the color of a xml property: `app:footerColor="#1573D6"` dynamically during runtime. How can I achieve this?

I could change the layout too during the running of the App, but I looked for how to do it and couldn't find anything.

Some help would be great. Thank you very much.

Here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/tabloid"

        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:background="#000000"    
        android:textColor="#1573D6"
        app:footerColor="#1573D6"

        app:footerLineHeight="2dp"
        app:footerIndicatorStyle="none"

        app:selectedColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:selectedBold="true" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Why are you reposting this question?

Comment: Please post: the **complete** xml and some code, where the change should occur

Comment: Now with all xml code

Comment: @Muel because i think nobody saw my other post and I haven't receive any answers unfortunately

Comment: @user3050910 I answered your other post with pretty much the exactly the same answer as supplied to this post! You could have saved some time and typing by checking your original post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in code:

TitlePageIndicator indicator =(TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.yourview)

indicator.SetFooterColor(Color.parse( #1573D6))

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much sir, now I learned more. Thank you for sharing!!